# Is there a more generalized version of the extension axiom that can handle multisets?

Tags: logic, set-theory

That is, distinguishing between 2++ sets where at least one of the sets has elements with multiplicity >1. So if x and y are 2 distinct objects, and

S = {x,y} and T = {x,x,y}

the classic extension axiom cannot distinguish them because the both have x and y in them but T has 2 copies of x.Even though one could show that there is no bijective mapping between S and T.

Or even more tricky, the situation were we have the sets

A = {x,x,y} and B = {x,y,y}

These sets(A,B) are also indistinguishable by the Axiom of Extension because they have the same types of elements and they also have the same cardinality.

But if you look at the powersets of S and T we have:

p(S) = ({x},{y},S,0) and p(T) = ({x},{y},S,{x,x},T,0)

So by extension, p(S) and p(T) do not have the same elements and neither do p(A) and p(B):

p(A) = ({x},{y},{x,x},{x,y},A,0) and p(B) = ({x},{y},{y,y},{x,y},B,0)

Comment: If you agree that $S$ and $T$ are indistinguishable, then so are $p(S)$ and $p(T)$. You may think that $p(T)$ contains $\{x,x\}$ and $p(S)$ does not - but $\{x,x\}$ is not distinguishable from $\{x\}$ and that is in $p(S)$. - T treat multisets, you may want extend the language beyond the $\in$ relation in the first place

Comment: A multiset $M$ can be a set with multiplicity, i.e. for every element $a \in M$ we have its *multiplicity* $\mu(a)=n$. Thus, two multisets are equal iff they have the same elements and for each element the same multiplicity.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA that's kinda what I was looking for. But that involves the natural numbers which have to be constructed from the basic axioms of set theory. And suppose we are dealing with an infinite set that has infinitely many copies of a certain elements? That's the trouble: distinguishing sets which may/may not be multisets independent of their cardinality.And if their elements are not unique then 2++ sets can't be distinguished by their elements alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multisets don't feature in the most widely used versions of set theory.  Those who want them can construct them, within a standard theory, as functions mapping "elements" to positive integers; so for example the multiset $[[x, x, y]]$ is the function that maps $x$ to 2 and $y$ to 1.  There is no need for any special axioms; the condition for equality of multisets is just the condition for equality of functions.

That said, axiomatic theories incorporating multisets from the ground up do exist. Blizzard for instance replaces the binary relation of containment $\in$ between an element and a set by a ternary relation between element, positive integer, and set; "$x \in^n A$" means "$A$ contains $x$ with multiplicity $n$". Then his axiom of extension states that sets $A$ and $B$ are equal if, for all $x$ and $n$, $x \in^n B$ if and only if $x \in^n A$.

Naturally, such theories don't attempt to construct the set of integers, which is one of the things mathematicians expect from a set theory. Some computer scientists, though, seem to like them.

Comment: One can construct the set of integers from the Von Neumann ordinals, which are distinguishable from each other using the axiom of extension. But clearly the multiset binary operator requires the natural numbers. And in the case of infinite sets and infinite multiplicity you would need to extend that.

Comment: So perhaps a better statement is that the subsets of elements that are identical from any 2 sets have a bijective mapping between them.

Comment: @MrX And then you'd need to take bijection as a preexisting notion.  The upshot I think is that if you want multisets as a primitive you can have them; but you can't have them as an extra feature in a standard set theory; you end up with a different kind of theory serving different purposes.